# Rails Sass Custom Method Not Being Ran

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sass, ruby-on-rails-4.2, sass-rails

For some reason sass isn't running my custom function. The environment variable is defined and working as I have other ruby code that uses it within the app. I just can't figure out why SASS isn't running the function. I appreciate your help.

I have a custom sass method located in the application.rb file:

```
module Sass::Script::Functions
  def get_env
    Sass::Script::String.new(ENV['THE_ENV'])
  end
  declare :get_env, args: []
end
```

`THE_ENV` environment variable is defined in the application.yml file.

In my application.sass file I have the following, It's always setting #d71f2b:

```
$primary_color: #d71f2b
@if get_env() == "xyz"
  $primary_color: #39A163
@else
  $primary_color: #d71f2b
```

Gemfile.lock contains:

```
  sass (3.4.22)
  sass-rails (5.0.4)
    railties (>= 4.0.0, < 5.0)
    sass (~> 3.1)
    sprockets (>= 2.8, < 4.0)
    sprockets-rails (>= 2.0, < 4.0)
    tilt (>= 1.1, < 3)
```

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. My application.yml file shows `THE_ENV: xyz`. The sass ruby code is looking for `"xyz"` including the quotes. I removed the quotes from the sass ruby if/else statement and it worked. So it looks like:

```
$primary_color: #d71f2b
@if get_env() == xyz
  $primary_color: #39A163
@else
  $primary_color: #d71f2b
```